# Printing all claffication classes in vgg, keras. IndexError

Tags: python, printing, keras, index-error, pre-trained-model

I'm trying to print out all known classes with their probability values. The first value is the class with the highest probability.

Here is my code so far:

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
from keras.applications.vgg16 import decode_predictions

model = VGG16()

print(model.summary())


# load an image from file
image = load_img('./pictures/door.jpg', target_size=(224, 224))
image = img_to_array(image)  #output Numpy-array

#4-dimensional: samples, rows, columns, and channels.
image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2]))


# prepare the image for the VGG model. 
image = preprocess_input(image)


# predict the probability across all output classes. 
yhat = model.predict(image)


# convert the probabilities to class labels
label = decode_predictions(yhat)
# retrieve the most likely result, e.g. highest probability
for i in range(0,5):
    label = label[i][i]
    print('%s (%.2f%%)' % (label[1], label[2] * 100))
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File path, line 38, in <module>
    print('%s (%.2f%%)' % (label[1], label[2] * 100))
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Do you have any idea how to handle it?
Thanks in advance^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your code. Try this out:

```
labels = decode_predictions(yhat)[0]
# retrieve the most likely result, e.g. highest probability
for i in range(0,5):
    label = labels[i]
    #print('%s (%.2f%%)' % (label[1], label[2] * 100)) 
    print('%s (%.2f%%)' % (label[1], float(label[2]) * 100))
```

Comment: I guess you mean label[i]. If I correct it, i get a TypeError: a float is required

Comment: No, I mean labels[i]. That way it is working for me.

Comment: I coppied your answer. This is the exception     print('%s (%.2f%%)' % (label[1], label[2] * 100))
TypeError: a float is required

Comment: can you print labels?

Comment: print('%s (%.2f%%)' % (label[1], float(label[2]) * 100))
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'

Comment: can you do print(labels)?

Comment: just edit labels to
labels = decode_predictions(yhat)[0]

Comment: Do you actually have any idea how to get the list of all known classes?